# How to Document return of type Record<K, V> using Nestjs OpenApi?

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, openapi

I Have an endpoint that will return a TypeScript Record type. However, when i use the `@ApiOkResponse` from NestJs to document it, I receive the error: `'Record' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`.

Im trying to do it like this:

```js
@Get('my/endpoint')
@ApiOkResponse({
  type: Record<KeyEnum, ValueClass>,
  description: 'some description',
})
public async myEndpoint(): Promise<Record<KeyEnum, ValueClass>> {
  return this.myService.method();
}
```

Comment: in short, types doesn't exists in runtime, this is why you cannot use type aliases nor interfaces from TS. If you want to use `type` (and not `schema`) you should turn this `Record<KeyEnum, ValueClass>` into a js class